# Brownie classmethod Contract.from_abi() creates Namespace error for info() function

Tags: ethereum, web3py, brownie

I have existing external contract what I would like to load with:
`contract = Contract.from_abi(contract_name, address, abi_json)`

Contract info() function creates Namespace collision with brownie.network.contract class. If I try to execute contract.info() then it returns "None" but it should have had returned string text with value "You will find what you need in info1().". Other functions for contract work fine. Is there a way to get rid of Namespace error and execute contract.info()?

Link to Brownie Contract.from_abi() doc: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html?highlight=from_abi#Contract.from_abi

Below is error message from terminal:

```
/home/peteris/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/contract.py:794: 
BrownieEnvironmentWarning: Namespace collision between contract function and brownie `Contract` class member: 'Instance.info'
The info function will not be available when interacting with Instance
  warnings.warn(
```

Comment: Great question.. this might actually make for an issue on the official brownie github.

Comment: @PatrickCollins thank you for reply! I created an issue for brownie github: https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1349